# Can I use whatsapp with a number belonging to another phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I currently have a Samsung S5 phone but find it bulky to carry and as I use it mainly for old fashioned calls I was thinking of moving my simcard (and therefore phone number) to my old Motorola Razr. 
I understand that the S5 will effectively become like a small tablet and the email will still work on the S5 but will whatsapp if I am using the number on another phone?
Will my whatsapp contacts notice any difference or will it work exactly as it currently does?
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Answer is 'Yes', you can use it on your S5 seamlessly while using SIM in another device.

• Your Whatsapp contacts doesn't see any change.

• Remember Whatsapp can only be use on single device at a time(not whatsapp web) that means if you try to open it in your Moto device than you Galaxy device 's account will be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I think I am in a good position to answer this question. You can always use a WhatsApp account with a no which isn't available in the device. I have been doing this for years. But please make sure that you setup a security code feature after successful completion of WhatsApp setup in the desired phone, which will secure you from being hijacked if the no(WhatsApp) lost!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it on your S5 while using the SIM in another device.

1. You have to copy contact to that mobile.
2. Use the OTP that comes by SMS on that number to put on the mobile you want to use Whatsapp.
3. Sync your old chats from Google mail id,  you use to store back up.

**Note:** Whatsapp can only be used on a single device, so only use one account associated only one mobile number.

**Suggestion:**  You can also use Whatsapp Web to use Whatsapp on your laptop or computer without changing SIM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, I have done it my times. Even the number is no more active, you still can use it for your WA. Like my WA's number right now, the number itself already deactivated by the operator since around 2 years ago. But I still use the number for my WA.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

- Your S5 will still be usable for WhatsApp, with your phone number.
- Your WA contacts will keep the same.

**Important notes**:

1. Every phone number can be used with WA on a single device. Using WA with that phone number on another device enforces closing the WA account in the previously associated device.
2. Be aware that, when you insert your Sim card in another phone (Moto Razr here), if it has WhatsApp installed, the phone may prompt about "updating the account" (or the like) in a cryptic way, and not explicitly stating that it refers to WhatsApp (this depends on versions of OS and WA).
   If you answer "yes" (assuming it relates to the phone/line, not WA), the number will be used for WA in the Moto Razr, and **it will be automatically removed from the S5.**
   You will need to associate again the number with WA installed in the S5.
   It may be a problem if you do not have your Sim card at hand, as it happened to me before.
3. Be aware that, if you insert a new Sim card in the S5, WhatsApp may prompt for changing the number associated with the WA account (this depends on versions of OS and WA).
   You have to decide what you want to do.
4. The latest Android versions allow for having two WhatsApp accounts in a single phone (likewise for Viber, Telegram, etc.), with [Dual Messenger](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/about-dual-messenger/).
   This required before the use of [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl&hl=en) or the like.
   So for the case above, if you configure it properly, **you may keep you old WA account in the S5, and also have your new number associated with WA in your S5**.
   I have exactly this.